# Se puede ejecutar un funcion de javascript desde un Controlador con un ActionResult?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc

No sé si pueda pero necesito ejecutar una instrucción en javascript que me devuelva un valor. Pero necesito hacerlo desde un ActionResult de un controlador en ASP.NET MVC

Aclaración: Ya sé que es codigo de cliente en el código de servidor pero solo queria saber si se puede...

Por ejemplo:

```
Public ActionResult GetInfo(){

  //Ejecutar una funcion de javascript y que me devuelva un valor
  // <script>GetPermission(){ return Notification.permission;}</script>
  // Y usar GetPermission ya en c# del lado del servidor
  // string _permission= GetPermission();

  return View();
}
```

Gracias a toda la comunidad!

Comment: lo mejor que usted puede hace es realizar una peticion por ajax,aunque el asp.net mvc no es un lenguanje que domino bien

Comment: Hola. Por qué esa necesidad? No vas a poder ejecutar código de cliente en el servidor. Puedes explicar un poco más la funcionalidad que necesitas?

Comment: necesito informacion del browser del cliente y llevarlo al backend o controller para persitir esa informacion

Comment: SignalR, haces comunicación en tiempo real y con esto te permite ejecutar cosas del backend desde el frontend, al igual que cosas del frontend desde el backend :D

Comment: Amigo porque no ejecuta un función c# en vez de javascript para obtener los permisos y los devuelve a la vista en un modelo de la pagina return View(modelo)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si se puede hice algo parecido

```
 MVELEntitiess dbCont = new MVELEntitiess();
        var count = from query5 in dbCont.tb_fuente_parametro//Query para comparar datos obtenidos de excel con la DDBB si es != de null se actualiza
                    where query5.Manual.ToString().ToLower() == ("S").ToString().ToLower() && query5.Codigo_fuente.ToString() == ("7").ToString()
                    select query5.Manual;

        var contador = "";
        if ((count != null) && (count.Count() > 0))
        {

            contador = (count).ToString();

        }
        ViewData["bloquear"] = contador;//Envio un viewdata al js que lo recibo como "Bloquear"


        return View("~/Views/CargaCMGmt/CargaCMGmt.aspx");
    }
```

Acá la vista

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
             <% if (ViewData["bloquear"] == "") //Si bloquear esta vacío bloqueo mi boton Submit y de esta manera recibo el parametro desde el controlador
        { %>
        $("#botoncargar").attr('disabled', 'disabled');

        <% } %>
    </script>
```